# What should be our conduct when we do not agree with an answer, or we don't understand it?

Tags: discussion

I've recently posted a question. A user posted an answer with which I had some doubts with. We exchange a decent amount of comments(10 or more) where I would say that his answer did something not allowed, and the user said it didn't. Maybe I'm wrong and I'm not getting it, either way, he stopped trying to explain me, as any reasonable person would, and I'm still not convinced.

Should I just post another question on ME with the answer from that user, ask who's right?

Note: the question with the answer and the comments is [Conditions for convergence of moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871135/conditions-for-convergence-of-moments)   (edited Will Jagy)

Comment: As you seem to have already [decided on your approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/871718/8348), do you still want our suggestions?

Comment: Not sure the new post is a good idea... I added my two cents about the proof in the first post as a comment. (By the way, said proof is correct and the interplay between $M$ and $\varepsilon$ there is rather usual--so much so that this is a good idea to try to master it in depth.)

Comment: Many thanks for everything. I've decided to delete the new post. I guess I should have waited for some answers.

@ArthurFischer, the original question was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871718/application-of-definition-of-limit .